# How to consolidate multiple query results using parse.com and JavaScript SDK?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Using parse.com and JavaScript SDK.

I have two queries that both work, but I'd like to consolidate the results into one, so that I ca then display the different fields next to each other on the html page.

What would be the best approach to do this? The queries use different classes.

I was looking at the user guides and was thinking using something like a compound query?

```
var mainQuery = Parse.Query.or(queryOne, queryTwo);
```

but not sure if I need to do that and if I could actually just nest them instead?

Query 1

```
 var GlobalBadges = Parse.Object.extend("Global_Badges");
 var query = new Parse.Query(GlobalBadges);
 query.exists("Global_Badges_img");
 query.find({
    success: function(results) {
        var friends = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            friends.push({
                imageURL: results[i].get('Global_Badges_img'),
                //friendRequestId: results[i].id,
                badgename: results[i].get('BadgeName'),
                category: results[i].get('category')
            });
        }
```

Query 2

```
var toUser = new Parse.User();
        toUser.id = toUserId;

        var myBadges = Parse.Object.extend("myBadges");
        var query = new Parse.Query(myBadges);

        query.equalTo("SentTo", toUser);
        query.find({
            success: function(Badgeresults) {
                // If the query is successful, store each image URL in an array of image URL's
                var Badges = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < Badgeresults.length; i++) {

                        Badges.push({
                    imageURL: Badgeresults[i].get('BadgeName'),
                    AwardedBy: Badgeresults[i].get('uploadedBy').get('username'),
                    AwardedTo: Badgeresults[i].get('SentTo').get('username'),
                    comment: Badgeresults[i].get('Comment'),


                });

            }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "consolidating the results into one". Are the queries related at all? They seem to be different objects with nothing in common.

Comment: @Dano007, was your issue solved?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, and you're just needing to render the results of two different queries to your page, the easiest way would be to have one of the queries take place in the **success** callback of the other query. Something like the following:

```
render: function() {
  var _this = this;
  var productQuery = new Parse.Query('Product');
  var itemQuery = new Parse.Query('Item');

  productQuery.find({
    success: function(products) {
      itemQuery.find({
        success: function(items) {
          _this.$el.html(_this.template({
            products: products,
            items:    items
          }));
        },
        error: function(error) {
          // WHATEVER
        }
      });
    },
    error: function(error) {
      // WHATEVER
    }
  });
}
```